# How to update XML using DOM with conditions in java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml, I want to update the data correspond only when two conditions are entered from frame examples: categories type="story" and url="story 1"

```
<root>
<categories type="story">
    <website url="story 1">update 1</website> 
    <website url="story 2">update 2</website>
</categories>
<categories type="other">
    <website url="other 1">update 3</website>
  </categories>
</root>
```

The statement I try to do, but failed.

```
try {
        Element root = null;
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse("file.xml");
        root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("categories");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (txtStory.getText().equals(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue())) {
                NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
                //**I begin to fail when trying to check url**
                for (int j = 1; j <= childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                    Element childNode = (Element) childNodes.item(j);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: What keeps you from doing it? I don't see any problem, because I don't see any code or error message.

Comment: In what way are you failing? Is there an exception? Please share the stack trace with us (use `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of swallowing the exception with `ex.getMessage()`)